# Как узнать длину строки в пикселях в Gwt, если известен шрифт?

Tags: gwt, java

ведь font metrics (java.awt.FontMetrics) - недоступны

Answer (score -1, accepted):

На данный момент такого способа нет, нужно писать workaround.